# Not able to open the terminal in the vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am getting this error whenever i am trying to open the terminal in the vs code. The terminal process command 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Node.js' failed to launch (exit code: 2)

Comment: Have you tried to reboot your PC?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i changed "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Node.js " back to "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" 
so now i am able to open terminal.